# Case checking with regex?

Tags: python, regex, substitution

What regex can I use to check if there is an excessive number of capitals in a word? e.g.

```
AAAApples
```

The program should match `AAAApples` as having too many capital letters at the start, and using `re.sub`, replace them with empty strings to leave `Apples`

So using regex, this: `r'^[A-Z]*[a-z]'` finds capitals, and checks that the next is a lowercase letter. I then replace this with an empty string, to remove the capitals. But of course, this then also removes 'Ap', leaving 'ples'.

What do I need to do to my regex to fix this?

Comment: You need to define your requirements more precisely. How many is "too many"? Do they have to be repetitions of the same letter, or is it just any sequence of capitals, like `ABCDApples`?

Comment: 'too many' is more than one before a lowercase letter, and it could be any sequence of capitals

Comment: What is the expected result for `APples`?

Comment: What is the expected result for IBM or HP? Sometimes multiple consecutive capital letters are actually correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a capture group to get the letters after the extra capitals.

```
re.sub(r'^[A-Z]+([A-Z][a-z])', r'\1', string)
```

This matches a sequence of uppercase letters, followed by an uppercase and then lowercase letter. The parentheses cause the match for the last two letters to be put in a capture group. In the replacement `\1` is replaced with the contents of the first capture group.

Or you can use lookahead:

```
re.sub(r'^[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z])', '', string)
```

A lookahead specifies that the pattern matches only if it's followed by a match for the sub-pattern, but that sub-pattern isn't included in the match. So this matches a sequence of uppercase letters that must be followed by an uppercase and then lowercase letter. But only the initial sequence of uppercase letters is included in the match, which then gets replaced by the empty string.

Go to [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) to learn all about regexp.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I have only just recently discovered regex, can you explain how those two solutions worked? Just so I know what I am typing is actually doing